# What is a ket of a vector with a bra of another one?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose we have an orthonormal basis $\{ \psi \}$ in finite dimension of a hilbert space;
What is the butterfly operator of a sum of the $ \psi  $, say $\psi_i +\psi_j$ ?

Since by linearity of "taking the dual" we must have, writing $B$ for but..terfly,
$\lvert\psi_i +\psi_j\rangle\langle\psi_i +\psi_j \rvert = B_i + B_j + \lvert \psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j\rvert + \lvert\psi_j\rangle\langle\psi_i\rvert$
but I have never seen expressions like $\lvert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_j\rvert$ when $i$ and $j$ are different.

What happens when we relax orthonormality to get a general basis ?
When we impose $\langle\psi_j\lvert\psi_i\rangle = \delta_{ij}$, what is the subspace the operator?
How to visualize it?

What if we have another basis $\{ \phi \}$ and impose $\langle\phi_j\lvert \psi_i \rangle = \delta_{ij}$; what does it mean to look at $\lvert\phi_j\rangle\langle\psi_i\rangle$?
Can we say more than "it is projecting on $\lvert\phi_j\rangle$ when we take a ket and projection on $\langle\psi_i\rangle$ when we take a bra?